# Entity Framework takes about 30 seconds on first query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 on a SQL Server database to query an existing database (database first, so there's an EDMX in my project).

I've noticed that the first time I request an entity, it can take up to thirty seconds for the query to be executed. Subsequent queries to the same object then get completed in a matter of milliseconds. The actual SQL being executed is very fast so it's not a slow query.

I've found that Entity Framework generates views on the background and that this is the most likely culprit. What I haven't found, however, is a good solution for this. There's a NuGet package that can handle the View Generation (EFInteractiveViews), but it hasn't been updated since 2014 and I hardly seem to find any information on how to use it.

What options do I have nowadays? I've tried initializing Entity Framework on Application_Start by doing a few queries, but this doesn't seem to help much at all, and also it's quite difficult to perform the real queries on `Application_Start`, because most queries use data from the current user (who is not yet logged on at `Application_Start`) so it's difficult to run these in advance.

I've thought about creating an ashx file that constantly polls the application by calling the API and keep it alive. I've also set the Application Pool to "AlwaysRunning" so that EF doesn't restart when the app pool is recycled.

Does anyone have any tips or ideas on how I can resolve this or things I can try?

Thanks a lot in advance. I've spent the better part of two days already searching for a viable solution.

Comment: What db do you use?

Comment: Oh sorry, SQL Server. I'll update my question

Comment: You could try disabling the proxy creation using `myContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`. I personally disable lazy loading so to be explicit with the code, so i also `myContext.Configuration.LazyLoading = false;`

Comment: @Darren: thanks for the suggestion. What effects does this have on lazy loading? I've been reading up on proxy creation just now and it seems like this will no longer (optimally) work. Any ideas?

Comment: Lazy loading allows deferred loading of related entities. So you could do MyUser.Account (where account is another entity) without having specifically loading Account (as soon as you do .Account the DB will be hit again). Seems like an awesome idea but for me there is no substitute for requesting exactly what you want in 1 call rather than a series of deferred hits to the DB.

Comment: I had a similar issue with an ASP.NET web app that the very first EF query would take 20-35 seconds - usually after a fresh deploy, or when the app pool had been recycled. I spent a lot of time profiling and trying to speed it up, without much success in the end. It appears that this time is spent by EF building up it's in-memory model that it needs to run your queries - and I haven't found a way to do this "on demand"; e.g. right after a deploy, before the first request this the web site

Comment: @marc_s you can "warm up" the site, but a better idea would be to break the model into smaller, scenario-specific models.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I tried the "site warm up", which worked OK for lookup tables (caching their values into .NET cache), but it didn't really do anything to bring down the EF startup time for the very first query ....

Answer (score 4):

There are many practices to speed up Entity Framework, I will mention some of them

1. Turn off the LazyLoading (EDMX => open the file right click anywhere => properties => `Lazy Loading Enabled` set it to false )
2. Use `AsNoTracking().ToList()` and when you want to update, use `Attach` and update object state to `EntityState.Modified`
3. Use `Indexes` on your table
4. Use `Paging`, do not load all the data at once
5. Split your `Edmx` into many smaller, only include the ones you need in your page, ( this will effect the performance in good way)
6. If you want to load related objects "be eager and not lazy", use `Include`, you might include `using System.Data.Entity` to use the lambda include features

Example for splitting your Edmx

If you have the following objects for a rent a car app : `Country`, `City` , `Person`, `Car`, `Rent`, `Gender`, `Engine`, `Manufacturers`,..etc.

Now

- If you are working on a screen to Manage (CRUD) person, this means you don't need Car,Rent,Manufacturer, so create `ManagePerson.edmx` contains ( `Country`, `City`, `Person`, `Gender`)
- If you are working on managing (CRUD) Car then you don't need (Person,City, Gender,Rent), so you can create `ManageCar.edmx` containing ( `Car`, `Manufacturer`,`Country`, `Engine`)

Comment: Not sure i see the point of splitting the EDMX up. AFAIK Nothing in there does anything until called upon.

Comment: @Darren I ensure at least point 5,  splitting EDMX into many smallar edmx  will minimize the warm up time, I tested this with code first approach, I had  DbContext with 600+ DBSets , I created around 50 DbConext each serves  a separate context, the first run waiting time dropped around 70%

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I'm looking into some of them, but a quick question: working with multiple EDMX's, is it the same as working with multiple diagrams? I can select an Entity in the edmx file and select "move to new diagram". Will this do anything?

Comment: if you look underneath `EDMX` in the generated code .cs, you will find `DBSets` and inherited from `DBContext`, the number of `DBSets` should be the minimum to serve your context, regarding your question, I am far from the testing machine, but as I mentioned, if moving the entity to another diagram will remove `DbSet` code from the first diagram generated code then yes otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework must first compile and translate your LINQ queries into SQL, but after this it then caches them. The first hit to a query is always going to take a long time, but as you mention after that the query will run very quickly.

When I first used EF it was constantly an issue brought up by testers, but when the system went live and was used frequently (and queries were cached) it wasn't an issue.

See Hadi Hassans answer for general speed up tips.

Comment: I know. 30 seconds is a massive amount of time though (and try explaining that to your end users). Also, this 30-second hits seems to appear more-or-less everytime a new entity is queried. For instance, I have an Organization. The very first time anyone tries to view the list of Organizations, there is a 30 second hit. There's also a list of Publications, with the exact same problem, regardless of whether or not the Organizations have already been loaded. Load time varies but it's usually around 20 - 30 seconds per Entity

Comment: @StevenLemmens you probably have a very big model. That's generally a bad idea, as a model should only contain what is relevant for a specific scenario. It should *not* be a map of the entire domain. It's not just for performance, one big model that tries to cover all scenarios, will end up mapping and loading a lot of useless data

Comment: @StevenLemmens: This sounds like not the model, but the query creation takes the majority of your time. Since precompiled queries are not supported since the introduction of DbContext, you could try to execute (and therefore also compile) the queries- not necessarily with any result data - upon initializing, or when there is not much load on the application/asynchronously.